How can I use Hammerspoon to allow me to use Windows and macOS hotkeys?
I'm coming from using Linux or Windows.
For example, I'm trying to allow myself to use cmd+c or ctrl+c to copy text in macOS. This is the Hammerspoon script I have, but it doesn't seem to be working:
-- Create an event tap for keyDown and keyUp events
controlToCommandTap = hs.eventtap.new(
    {hs.eventtap.event.types.keyDown, hs.eventtap.event.types.keyUp},
    function(evt)
        -- Get the frontmost application
        local frontmostApp = hs.application.frontmostApplication()

        -- If Terminal is frontmost, do not modify the event
        if frontmostApp and frontmostApp:name() == "Terminal" then
            return false
        end

        local flags = evt:getFlags()

        -- If the event includes the Control key, transform it into a Command key press
        if flags.ctrl then
            flags.ctrl = nil    -- remove ctrl flag
            flags.cmd = true    -- add cmd flag
            evt:setFlags(flags)

            -- Suppress the original event and return the modified one
            return true, {evt}
        end

        return false
    end
)


I was missing this at the end of the Lua script.
…
        return false
    end
)
controlToCommandTap:start()

Now it works well and both ctl and cmd hotkeys work!
